# Redirect Tomcat Embedded 8 Log

Tags: java, tomcat, logging, tomcat8, embedded-tomcat-8

I have a web app in Spring Boot that can take a war file and deploy it with embedded tomcat 8.
So, for each uploaded war file I do the following

```
Tomcat tomcat = new Tomcat();
tomcat.setPort(port);
File catalinaHome = new File(TOMCAT_DIR + port);
catalinaHome.mkdirs();
File webapp = new File(TOMCAT_DIR + port + "\\webapps");
webapp.mkdir();
tomcat.setBaseDir(catalinaHome.getAbsolutePath());

try {
    File war = new File("myapp.war");
    StandardContext context = (StandardContext) tomcat.addWebapp("/myapp", war.getAbsolutePath());
    context.setAntiResourceLocking(true);
    tomcat.start();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I don't have any idea how can I redirect the output.
I read that tomcat embedded log to `System.out`, and I was able to redirect to file with:

```
PrintStream out = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("output.txt"));
System.setOut(out);
```

but redirect all output, and I want something that log to a different file for each tomcat instance that I run.
Any solution that I found so far don't resolve my problem.
Thanks

Comment: Do you want to redirect the Tomcat log to your webapp log?

Comment: I want to redirect each tomcat instance log to a different file